# How to append content from a php file into a div with jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, append, partial-page-refresh

**Goal:** I'm trying to refresh content inside a div so that if the user is logged in, the page changes dynamically.

**Progress:** My first attempt was to use `$("#tab_b").load("php/tabs.php  #tab_b");` but this didn't update the DOM so the jquery styling didn't get applied. Then I tried adding the .trigger('create') function `$("#tab_b").trigger('create');` This only led the style blink on and off for a fraction of a sec. Then I tried the .append() function which seems to work, I'm using the following code to test the function and this works:

```
$("#tab_b").html('');
$("#tab_b").append("<button type='submit' data-theme='a'>Test button</button>").trigger('create');
```

the only problem I have is fetching the content from the php file and then appending it to the div.

**Content that should be refreshed:** " #tab_b "

```
<div id="tab_b" class="content_div">    
    <?php

    if(!isLoggedIn())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        echo("
        <button type='submit' data-theme='a' id='logout' >Logout</button>
         ");
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Any idea's on how to do this? Also Any suggestions on improvements are welcome, I'm a beginner programmer.

This question is an attempt to solve a bigger problem discussed in my other topic:

[jQuery Mobile does not apply styles after dynamically loading content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9871111/1251989)

Comment: When do you call the trigger('create') method?

Comment: I chain it right after the $(#tab_b).append( .. ).trigger('create');

Comment: I think you need to refresh the page after the page loads, look into the Events API: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work:

```
$( '#tab_b' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

I would look into the Event API

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm not sure how this reloads the content of the div? I've read the doc file but i'm not getting any wiser from it. Could you provide some kind of example perhaps? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can fetch data with $.ajax function. This returns the whole page. 
My solution was to move the content that needed to be refreshed to a new php page, 
tab_b.php and load it from there. Not sure if this is the best solution but it works.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'php/tab_b.php',
     success: function (data) {
          $("#tab_b").html('');
          $("#tab_b").append(data).trigger('create');
     }
});
```